# Sequelize Limit not working when using Sequelize literal in Where condition

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have the below relation:
`Organisation.hasMany(OrganisationAdmins)` (assume that alias and all are given correctly).

Now when I am trying to find all organisation's without an organisation admin, its causing issue on limit. Earlier i was unable to do this, then i saw that i can use sequelize literal to find organisations without organisationadmins. But then the issue was that `limit` is no more working properly. Its always giving 1 records in the result. I even tried using `subquery:false` and `duplicating:false` in includes, but still no luck. Can someone really help? The desired result is all organisations list which don't have Admins, with a `limit` (pagination). It works correctly without pagination.

```
Organisation.findAndCountAll({
        where: Sequelize.literal('organisation_admins.organisation_id IS NOT null'),
        include : [{model: OrganisationAdmins, as : 'organisation_admins', required: false}],
        offset : skip,
        limit : limit,
        subQuery: false,
        order : [sort],
        distinct: true
});
```